# Create bubble sort code, but facing some errors

Tags: java

Had a problem with compilation, getting error

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem:
>
> at practise.code.main(code.java:11)

Here is my code:

```
package practise;

public class code {
    
    static int number[]={1,8,5,9,4,7};
    static int c[] = new int[number.length];
    static int p=0;
    static int q;
    
    
    public static void main(String[] args){
        
        change(number);
        
        System.out.println("Array Before Bubble Sort");  
        for(int y: c){  
                System.out.print(y + "\t");  
        }  
        
            
    }
    
    public static void change (int x[]){
        
        for(int a: x){
            
            for(int i=0; i<=x.length; i++){
                    
                if(a > x[i]){
                     continue;}
                else {
                      p++;}
            
            q = x.length - p - 1;
            
                c[q] = a;
                
                }
            
            }  
            
            
        }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: And the actual error...

Comment: First thing to do: stop trying to run code that doesn't compile. The compilation error should be visible to you immediately, and there's no benefit in running the code while it still doesn't compile.

Comment: What does the compiler say the problem is?

Comment: @4castle  
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 

 at practise.code.main(code.java:11)

Comment: @4castle  i tried even using switch for c[q] = a; with  all the cases but even then the error exists..

Comment: @takendarkk  

 i have updated the code now.. can you please check it once..!!

Comment: You *still* haven't posted the actual error though. Yes, there's a compilation error. What is it, and how have you tried to fix it?

Comment: @JonSkeet

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: at practise.code.main(code.java:11)

Comment: That's not a compiler error, that's a runtime error. I don't know how you're compiling the code, but it should be easy to find the compiler error.

Comment: @JonSkeet

i am new to coding. started learning java and practicing on Eclipse

Comment: @4castle runtime error..?? how can i resolve it. i am a newbee. donno anything about runtime errors..

i am using eclipse

Comment: Please go back to searching on Google until you at least have a grasp on the terminology. If you don't know the difference between an error and an exception, then you need to go back to even more basics.

Comment: Format the code properly.  Any code within a block (IE: `{}`) should be indented 2 or 4 spaces, with the closing `}` being on its own line and not indented.  Once you format this properly, your mistake will become immediately clear.

Comment: @takendarkk  what kind of exception is this.

at practise.code.main(code.java:11)   the line 11 in this is the main method it self



you mean there will be so solution for Exceptions like this..??

Comment: @Ironcache i have tried it even,  same error showing up..

Comment: Formatting your code properly will show you the error, not fix it for you.  If you have truly formatted it properly, then the reason the code is failing should be immediately obvious, and you'll be able to fix it.

Comment: I should clarify that I mean the reason your code isn't **compiling** will become immediately obvious; once it compiles, there may be other problems that need to be tackled.

Comment: @Ironcache  thank for the advice...

Comment: @Ironcache  Problem Solved...  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your advices... Finally made it working..

thank you once again

`package practise;

public class code{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int[] Array = {5,8,6,4};
        int[] newArray = new int[Array.length];
        int a, b, c, d, e, f =1;

        for(int z : Array ){
            d=0;
            for(int i=0; i<Array.length; i++){
                a = z; b = Array[i];

                if( a >= b){
                    continue;}
                else{
                    d++;}
                }
            c = Math.subtractExact(Array.length , d);
            e = Math.subtractExact(c, f);
            for(int j=0; j< Array.length; j++){
                while( j == e){
                newArray[j] = z;
                break;
                }
            }

        }

        System.out.println("Here is your old Array :");
        for(int k : Array){
            System.out.println(k);

        System.out.println("Here is your new Bubble Sort Array :");
        for(int q : newArray){
            System.out.println(q);
        }

        }
    }
}`

Answer (score 1):

Some meta-help for future reference:

**Compiler errors**: these are when you experience an error that occurs at compile time. For Java, this is when you use `javac`, and your Java code is being turned into bytecode files for interpretation later.

**Runtime errors**: this is when you experience an error that occurs when you run your code. For Java, this is when you use `java`, and your Java code is being run.

If you find the two confusing, add into your question the thing you typed in order to experience the error. Specify all the flags and options you used, and format it with a code block, for example like this:

```
java -jar code.jar
```

When asking questions here - or indeed anywhere on the web where you can get technical help - try to ask yourself what clarifications **you** would need if you saw your question for the first time. Your first edit did not include your code, so ask yourself: would you be able to ascertain someone else's similar problem without code? Broadly here the answer is "no", and thus the moral of this story is: always include your code.

Also, do spend a moment to learn the code formatting tools. To use them, paste your block of code into the question, select it, and click the "code" button. It will apply a four-space Markdown indent, which you can now see in the question.

If you need to add clarifications to your post, it is OK to add them as comments, but do also edit the body of the question so that new readers can understand the question. It is well worth spending time making it as readable and clear as possible, so you can get the best possible help, and so that people do not take a look and decide that another question is a better use of their time.

Since you are using an IDE, do you get any warnings/errors in the editor, to help you identify potential problems in you code? If so, and you do not understand them, then paste them into your question, in order to clarify it.